# User Profile Sync Creation + FIM error 22

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, sql-server, forefront

We encountered problems with the User Profile Synchronization in SharePoint 2013.

In the end we decided to re-create it, so we deleted the User Profile Service and kept the databases, however now when we try to re-create the service the following errors appear:

Error ID: 22 - The Forefront Identity Manager Service cannot connect to the SQL Database Server.

After going through some guides online I noticed that there was no Trusted certificate for the Forefront Identity Manager. Should this be the case since we have deleted the service?

Apart from this what could be wrong?

We can access the back end via the farm accounts so we don't believe it is related to credential failures etc as per the error message.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem we found was the database "SharePoint_Sync" was having issues - this was found after an in depth look into the Log files.

In the end we created a fresh version of that database and then recreated the user profile service via SharePoint admin. This had no errors and allowed us to run the full sync.